# Strings as template arguments

Tags: c++

While the C++ standards doesn't allow to use string literals as template-arguments, it is allowed things like this:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

> 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> 2 [ Note: A string literal (2.14.5) does not satisfy the requirements
>   of any of these categories and thus is not an acceptable
>   template-argument. [ Example:
>
> `template<class T, const char* p> class X { / ... / };`
>
> `X<int, "Studebaker"> x1; // error: string literal as template-argument`
>
> `const char p[] = "Vivisectionist";`
>   `X<int,p> x2; // OK`
>
> —end example ] —end note ]

So why the following code gives me an error in all compilers (gcc 4.7.2, MSVC-11.0, Comeau)?

```
template <const char* str>
void foo() {}

int main()
{
   const char str[] = "str";
   foo<str>();
}
```

Comment: +1 it used to work with something like MSCV 6 or 7. But last time I tried it no longer compiled :-( Glad you ask the question.

Answer (score 5):

Rewind a few lines.

14.3.2/1: a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with *static storage duration* and external or internal linkage.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the following modification works:

```
template <const char* str>
void foo() {}

char str[] = "str";

int main() {
    foo<str>();
}
```

See http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#stringliteral for a short explanation.

Comment: You're right, removing `const` helps. However, I think it just demonstrates a compiler bug in code handling constants, because `const char p[]=""` still defines an external object.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Oh yes, `const` is important here: compare http://ideone.com/rY7ZWI and http://ideone.com/u4LbEC (although you are right not using a local variable is essential, I was just trying variations of it and came across the `const` thing...)

Comment: Hmm, I think the term in the standard is "external linkage" (not "external object"). Objects having namespace scope declared `const` have internal linkage. I'm not a good language lawyer, but I don't think this is a compiler bug.

Comment: @jpalecek: Did you mean [http://ideone.com/t4jgHb](http://ideone.com/t4jgHb) and [http://ideone.com/0VBoi3](http://ideone.com/0VBoi3)? Also, yeah, I deleted my comment.

Comment: @mkluwe: According to n.m.'s quote it needs to be an object with "static storage duration and external or internal linkage" (so unless `const` makes it have non-static storage duration, it should theoretically work, regardless of whether it's external or internal linkage). I'm too lazy to figure out exactly how `const` affects this all, though. But I'd say it's a compiler bug, seeing as the standard's example code fails: [http://ideone.com/YQNCfB](http://ideone.com/YQNCfB)

Comment: You can keep the const, but then you have to ensure that it has external linkage.  (Const variables at namespace scope have internal by default.)  So `extern char const str[] = "str";` will work.  As will `static char const str[];` if it is a class member.  (An interesting point: using `static` at namespace scope guarantees that it won't work, `const` or not.  But you must make it `static` if it is a class member.)

Comment: @Cornstalks n.m.'s quote may be from the C++11 standard. The code compiles with gcc 4.72 using `-std=c++11` when changing `const` to `constexpr`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: And what of 14.3.2/1: "a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external **or internal linkage**"?

Comment: @mkluwe: Good to know, but does it still fail with the example code given by the C++ standard? If the standard says `const` should work, and it doesn't, I'd argue it's a compiler bug.

Comment: I can't answer that. I used `constexpr` because of the wording _constant expression_. The example shown above uses `const`, but IIRC in ISO standards, examples are non-normative.

Comment: @Cornstalks There's been a change between C++03 and C++11.  C++03 required template arguments to have external linkage; C++11 (I think) allows internal linkage as well.  Since generally speaking, one can't yet count on having C++11, it's better to use only external linkage.

Comment: @Cornstalks C++03 requires external linkage, and a const at namespace scope has internal linkage.  It's not a compiler bug (but one could argue that it is a bug in the standard).